# Multicolumn table: coefficients start a new line

Tags: tables, multicolumn

This is my Latex code for the regression table I want to create. As you can see when pasting it, the coefficients for Columns 9-12 create a new line and thus everything starts to be misaligned. Any suggestion? Thanks!!

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
 %\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption*{Table A1 }
\scalebox{0.65}{\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
    \hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Outcome1}                                         &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Outcome2}                                                   &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Putcome3}                                              \\[-0.05cm]\cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-13}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)}
%                    &    %column1        &    %column2        &    %column3        &    %column4        &    %column5        &    %column6        &    %column7        &    %column8        &    %column9        &   %column10        &   %column11        &   %column12        \\[-0.05cm]
\\ \hline \addlinespace[0.1cm]
Coeff1     &     0.00942$^{***}$&      0.0119$^{***}$&      0.0140$^{***}$&      0.0279$^{***}$&    -0.00540$^{***}$&    -0.00532$^{***}$&    -0.00828$^{***}$&     -0.0150$^{***}$&    -0.00513$^{***}$&    -0.00497$^{***}$&    -0.00674$^{***}$&     -0.0131$^{***}$\\[-0.05cm]
                    &   (0.00244)        &   (0.00251)        &   (0.00243)        &   (0.00257)        &   (0.00163)        &   (0.00165)        &   (0.00223)        &   (0.00244)        &   (0.00139)        &   (0.00142)        &   (0.00196)        &   (0.00221)        \\[-0.05cm]\addlinespace[0.15cm] 
Coeff2            &     0.00219        &      0.0324$^{***}$&     0.00504$^{*}$  &      0.0523$^{***}$&     0.00706$^{***}$&      0.0297$^{***}$&      0.0441$^{***}$&      0.0577$^{***}$&      0.0151$^{***}$&      0.0383$^{***}$&      0.0504$^{***}$&      0.0632$^{***}$\\[-0.05cm]
                    &   (0.00223)        &   (0.00279)        &   (0.00272)        &   (0.00335)        &   (0.00127)        &   (0.00158)        &   (0.00221)        &   (0.00276)        &   (0.00108)        &   (0.00142)        &   (0.00207)        &   (0.00262)        \\[-0.05cm]\addlinespace[0.15cm] 
Coeff3                &     0.00957$^{***}$&      0.0108$^{***}$&      0.0120$^{***}$&     0.00805$^{***}$&     -0.0225$^{***}$&     -0.0233$^{***}$&     -0.0265$^{***}$&     -0.0249$^{***}$&     -0.0102$^{***}$&     -0.0116$^{***}$&     -0.0126$^{***}$&     -0.0107$^{***}$\\[-0.05cm]
                    &   (0.00299)        &   (0.00291)        &   (0.00288)        &   (0.00284)        &   (0.00213)        &   (0.00208)        &   (0.00275)        &   (0.00278)        &   (0.00164)        &   (0.00166)        &   (0.00223)        &   (0.00220)        \\[-0.05cm]\addlinespace[0.15cm] 
\hline \addlinespace[0.1cm]
\end{tabular}}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: please provide a small complete document that shows the problem,  sidewaystable addlinespace are not defined scalebox are all defined in packages you have not mentioned

Comment: You get `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr` as you have not declared  enough columns

Comment: If you get any error ask about the error message not the pdf output you might get if you scroll past the error so `\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllll}` will work here (but dont apply `\scalebox` to tables, use `\small` if you must, but scaling will produce inconsistent font sizes

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry, new to the forum... thanks for the suggestion. Is there a way to adjust the size except for \small ? The reason is that it does not reduce the dimension so much. I used \tiny but that was too small.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indicated which document class you employ, which font and which font size you use, or how wide or narrow the margins are. The following solution assumes that the defaults for the `article` document class apply.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % '10pt' is the default font size
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\scriptsize % if the margins are narrower, you might get by with '\footnotesize'
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercolumn whitespace amounts
\caption*{Table A1 }
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{12}{c} @{}}
 \toprule
 &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Outcome1} 
 &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Outcome2}
 &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Putcome3} \\
 \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9} \cmidrule{10-13}
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)  & (5)  & (6) 
 & (7) & (8) & (9) & (10) & (11) & (12) \\
\midrule
Coeff1 
   &  0.00942$^{***}$&  0.0119$^{***}$ &  0.0140$^{***}$ & 0.0279$^{***}$
   & -0.00540$^{***}$& -0.00532$^{***}$& -0.00828$^{***}$& -0.0150$^{***}$
   & -0.00513$^{***}$& -0.00497$^{***}$& -0.00674$^{***}$& -0.0131$^{***}$ \\
   & (0.00244) & (0.00251) & (0.00243) & (0.00257) & (0.00163) & (0.00165) 
   & (0.00223) & (0.00244) & (0.00139) & (0.00142) & (0.00196) & (0.00221) \\ 
   \addlinespace 
Coeff2 
   & 0.00219         & 0.0324$^{***}$  & 0.00504$^{*}$   & 0.0523$^{***}$
   & 0.00706$^{***}$ & 0.0297$^{***}$  & 0.0441$^{***}$  & 0.0577$^{***}$
   & 0.0151$^{***}$  & 0.0383$^{***}$  & 0.0504$^{***}$  & 0.0632$^{***}$  \\
   & (0.00223) & (0.00279) & (0.00272) & (0.00335) & (0.00127) & (0.00158) 
   & (0.00221) & (0.00276) & (0.00108) & (0.00142) & (0.00207) & (0.00262) \\ 
   \addlinespace 
Coeff3 
   & 0.00957$^{***}$ & 0.0108$^{***}$  & 0.0120$^{***}$  & 0.00805$^{***}$
   & -0.0225$^{***}$ & -0.0233$^{***}$ & -0.0265$^{***}$ & -0.0249$^{***}$
   & -0.0102$^{***}$ & -0.0116$^{***}$ & -0.0126$^{***}$ & -0.0107$^{***}$ \\
   & (0.00299) & (0.00291) & (0.00288) & (0.00284) & (0.00213) & (0.00208) 
   & (0.00275) & (0.00278) & (0.00164) & (0.00166) & (0.00223) & (0.00220) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: that works perfectly excpet for \toprule and \bottomrule. These are the errors: Missing \cr inserted.
Missing } inserted.
Misplaced \cr.
Missing \endgroup inserted.
Misplaced \cr.

Comment: @tryingtogetsmth - Please be more specific as to what you're doing and how your code differs from what I posted above. For sure, the code I posted above compiles without error and generates the screenshot I posted.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by myself. Thanks a lot! The table is exactly what I was looking for!!